# Continuous Function Proof Question

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show what $f(x)=\frac{3}{2-x}$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

My attempt:

Let $a∈(0,1)$. Each $ε>0$ we have a $δ>0$ such that all $x∈(0,1)$ , $|x-a|<ε$, we have $|f(x)-f(a)|<ε$

$|f(x)-f(a)|=|\frac{3}{2-x}-\frac{3}{2-a}|$...  (I need to select a $ε$ due to this but how?)

I'm stuck here. Any advice/solution would be appreciated!

Comment: What about writing your last expression as a single fraction?

Comment: Thanks.It gives me $|\frac{3(x-a)}{(2-x)(2-a)}|$ From now on I need to pick a $ε$ value I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$0<a<1 \;\; \implies \;\; 1<2-a<2$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{2-a}<1$$

the same for $x$.

observe that

$$|f(x)-f(a)|\le 3|x-a|$$

Comment: It gives me $\frac{1}{|(2-x)(2-a)|}≤1$. So I need to pick $ε $ and  $δ$ value but I'm confused. I'm having a hard time choosing these values at every questions. Is there a easy way to determine these?